# Batch, How to count the number of the particular string in txt file

Tags: batch-file, text

The file, there is a "tab" between the each part.

```
00000420150331001014
C    A123456(7)  PAL    02.04.2015PM    08.04.2015PM
C    A123456(7)  PAL    02.04.2015PM    08.04.2015PM  
C    A123456(7)  PAL    02.04.2015PM    08.04.2015PM
C    A123456(7)  PAL    02.04.2015PM    08.04.2015PM
END
```

I want to write a batch script file using for loop to count how many `PAL` in the file.
But,due to my ability, i just can draft the following,any suggestion?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in (H071_20150331.TXT) do (
echo %%a 
pause
)
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the file format it'll be easier and faster to count with `find /c`:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('find/c " PAL " H071_20150331.TXT') do set count=%%a
echo %count%
pause
```

Comment: `for /f %%a in ('find /c " PAL " ^< H071_20150331.TXT') do set count=%%a` <--- redirecting the file into find.exe simplifies the code, noting that TAB characters need to be before and after PAL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the text `PAL` occurs at most once in a line, you could simply do:

```
@find /c "  PAL " H071_20150331.TXT
```

Note the tab characters before and after `PAL`. It's not possible to copy and paste tabs in the command line, but it's easy to enter them in a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid false positives like in `false xPALy`, use [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) rather than `find`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "delims=:" %%G in ('findstr /N "\<PAL\>" "H071_20150331.TXT"') do set "_cpal=%%G"
echo(%_cpal%
```

Regular expressions metacharacters `\<` and `\>` used as follows:

```
\<PAL     Word position: beginning of word 
PAL\>     Word position: end of word
```